# Javascript Typed array vs simple array: performance

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, dynamic-arrays, typed-arrays

What I'm basically trying to do is to map an array of data points into a WebGL vertex buffer (Float32Array) in realtime (working on animated parametric surfaces). I've assumed that representing data points with Float32Arrays (either one Float32Array per component: [xx...x, yy...y] or interleave them: xyxy...xy) should be faster than storing them in an array of points: [[x, y], [x, y],.. [x, y]] since that'd actually be a nested hash and all. However, to my surprise, that leads to a slowdown of about 15% in all the major browsers (not counting array creation time). Here's a little test I've set up:

```
var points = 250000, iters = 100;

function map_2a(x, y) {return Math.sin(x) + y;}
var output = new Float32Array(3 * points);

// generate data
var data = [];      
for (var i = 0; i < points; i++)
    data[i] = [Math.random(), Math.random()];
// run
console.time('native');
(function() {
    for (var iter = 0; iter < iters; iter++)
        for (var i = 0, to = 0; i < points; i++, to += 3) {
            output[to] = data[i][0];
            output[to + 1] = data[i][1];
            output[to + 2] = map_2a(data[i][0], data[i][1]);
        }
}());
console.timeEnd('native');

// generate data
var data = [new Float32Array(points), new Float32Array(points)];
for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    data[0][i] = Math.random();
    data[1][i] = Math.random();
}
// run
console.time('typed');
(function() {
    for (var iter = 0; iter < iters; iter++)
        for (var i = 0, to = 0; i < points; i++, to += 3) {
            output[to] = data[0][i];
            output[to + 1] = data[1][i];
            output[to + 2] = map_2a(data[0][i], data[1][i]);
        }
}());
console.timeEnd('typed');
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This does not pertain to your question, but you should avoid multiplication inside your main loops. Instead have an extra variable initialized to 0 before your inner loop, and do `+= 3` at the end of each inner loop's block.

Comment: Be sure to place each one inside it's own context so the variable redeclaration isn't causing issues. Wrap each test, leaving the top 3 lines out, inside of `(function() { /* ... test ... */ })()`

Comment: You did not mention what you are using to bench mark these. Be sure to use [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.time), and be sure only the code inside your `// run` area is included. There's no reason to assume Math.random() is constant time.

Comment: @JosephLennox Yup, I used to have a special testing function declared and put only the run part in ther, but didn't think it was relevant. And thanks for console.time, had a little bicycle invented instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are not comparing the same code.  In the first example, you have one large array filled with very small arrays.  In the second example, you have two very large arrays, and both of them need to be indexed.  The profile is different.

If I structure the first example to be more like the second (two large generic arrays), then the `Float32Array` implementation far outperforms the generic array implementation.

Here is a [jsPerf profile](http://jsperf.com/typed-vs-generic-arrays) to show it.

Comment: Although in fairness, the results are not consistent.  I get anywhere between 6% and 20% slower for the untyped array.

Comment: AND, for smaller-sized arrays, I am finding that the generic array still out-performs slightly in Chrome.  For the `points` you gave, it seems to be better to be native.  Go one order of magnitude up, and the native one is better yet.

Comment: And when the size of the array is another order of magnitude higher (25000000), the native array destroys the generic array.

Comment: The number of iterations seems to matter as well.  One time through, and the native implementation crushes it.  100 times through, and the results are a bit closer.  This would tell me that READING from the two arrays is closer in perf, but WRITING to the arrays is the actual perf savings.

Comment: Well yes, the profiles do differ, but each one seems to achieve the same goal in a way that's natural given the data type. Anyways, thanks for an insightful view!

Answer (score 0):

In V8 variables can have SMI (int31/int32), double and pointer type. So I guess when you operate with floats it should be converted to double type. If you use usual arrays it is converted to doubles already.